# JSON.stringify() causing an infinite loop (Edit: NO. Bad logic is.)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My product object looks somewhat like this:

```
{name: 'abc', description: 'def', price: 100, quantity: 1, comment: '', customizations: []}
```

The *customizations* key is an array that has other such product objects in it. You may ignore it for this question. As you might have noticed, the *comment* and *customizations* keys are the keys that make the (theoretically) **same** product (practically) **different** when adding to cart.

I want to make a function to add such products to an array called cart_items[]. If the (practically) same product is chosen, I only want to increment the *quantity* inside the cart_items[i], else add a new object.

This is my function:

```
    $scope.add_to_cart = function(product) {
// if the cart is empty, skip the brouhaha
            if ($scope.cart_items.length === 0) {
                $scope.cart_items.push(angular.copy(product));
            } else {
                for (var i = 0; i < $scope.cart_items.length; i++) {
// copy the original quantity and set it to 1 for comparison
                    var qty = $scope.cart_items[i].quantity;
                    $scope.cart_items[i].quantity = 1;
                    if (JSON.stringify(product) === JSON.stringify($scope.cart_items[i])) {
                        $scope.cart_items[i].quantity = qty + 1;
                    } else {
                        $scope.cart_items[i].quantity = qty;
                        $scope.cart_items.push(angular.copy(product));
                    }
                }
            }
        };
```

**The problem: First product adds successfully. Adding another causes an infinite loop.** I replaced `if(JSON...)` with `if(1 === 1)` and the infinite loop didn't occur. I don't know where am I going wrong. Any help?

Comment: It sounds like you have a circular reference in your product object, probably in the customizations array.

Comment: Also having `$scope.cart_items[i].quantity = qty;` in your `else` is going to change every product's quantity that does NOT match.  The `push` afterwards is also wrong, it will keep adding the product once per item already in the cart.

Comment: @James It's initialized with the quantity of the item.

Comment: @James: In that case I'm setting it back to qty later.

Comment: Ok I see that, the qty thing is still weird and unnecessary although not wrong.  The push is wrong though.  You want to loop through the cart items and then AFTER the loop add the new item if it was not found during the loop.

Comment: @James It's not really unnecessary : the purpose was to temporarely replace it with 1 in order to get the same JSON of a new item (which is very dangerous as I point in my answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you have is that you're increasing the size of the array in the loop and the stop condition is `i` being `$scope.cart_items.length`.

If your goal is to add the object if it's not yet present, what you want is probably this :

```
boolean found = false;
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.cart_items.length; i++) {
    var qty = $scope.cart_items[i].quantity;
    $scope.cart_items[i].quantity = 1;
    if (JSON.stringify(product) === JSON.stringify($scope.cart_items[i])) {
        $scope.cart_items[i].quantity = qty + 1;
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}
if (!found) {
    var item = angular.copy(product);
    item.quantity = 1;
    $scope.cart_items.push();
}
```

Note that two identical objects (i.e. objects with same property values) should **not** give the same JSON string because the order of property iteration isn't specified. It usually works (especially if the cloning is done the obvious way) but there's no guarantee. You really should compare based on the properties, **not** using JSON stringification.

Comment: Oh crap! How did I not notice this! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You probably enter in a recursive loop, because of objects contained in customizations...

```
A [ customizations = B ]
B [ customizations = C ]
C [ customizations = A ]
----------------------------
Infinite loop
```